# Vbscript scripting for adobe illustrator "rasterizeOptions"

Tags: vbscript, adobe, rasterize

I'm trying to make a vbscript for illustrator cc that selects all content on a layer named "test" and rasterizes it with a few settings.

I can't figure out how to use the "RasterizeOptions" class, I use vbsedit to browse trough the objects but from the moment I try:

```
CreateObject("Illustrator.RasterizeOptions")
```

[EDIT:] found out it's a class but i still can't find a way to make an instance of it...

[EDIT:] very silent on the adobe forum.. https://forums.adobe.com/message/9013828#9013828

I get the error it can't make the object?
How else should I create a RasterizeOptions object?
What am i doing wrong here?
can anyone show me an example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that object model, but usually you call a method on a higher object to get a reference to a lower object.

Comment: Can you give me a small example please? I looked up the Illustrator-Scripting-Reference but they say it's an object:     https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Reference-VBScript.pdf

Comment: In Scripting Runtime you call `Set FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"):Set TS = FSO.OpenAsTextStream` to get a text stream object. You can't create a text stream object, merely ask an object that can make it to do so.

Comment: @noodles Here is how they do it in java, but i don't know how to interpret java to convert it to vbs.. do i have to make an object or get it out of an other object? https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1592538

Comment: @Noodles, I just finished typing the previous message before i saw your reply, sorry..
ok, but with the object browser i can't find a way to make that object, not a single object that can give me the RasterizeOptions? it's like it's an object on it's own.. i wish i could post a print-screen of what i mean..

Comment: The java is using early binding so in VBS you use `Set RO = CreateObject("Illustrator.RasterOptions")` (check that spelling). If it's in a DLL the VBScript bitness must match the DLL bitness. Try using 32 bits to run script `c:\windows\SysWoW64\wscript script.vbs`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123704/discussion-between-tom-and-noodles).

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/message/9013828#9013828